# Word: Macro to set bookmark in a table column WITHOUT the first row

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working with macros in Microsoft Word. 
I need to reference the entire range of cells in a column, *except* the first row or "header".

My end goal is just to create VBA code that can cut all values in Column D and paste them into Column A.

I'm relying on bookmarks for this. I have a macro that creates a table, and then I want to insert something like:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add _
  Name:="ProposedMedTargets", Range:=Selection.Tables(1).Columns(6)
```

But I need this bookmark to exclude the first row. 
The range of cells is not static, as users may add a new row to the table at any time. 
I did try to find this online, but couldn't come across this specific use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short way.

```
    Selection.SetRange ActiveDocument.Tables(1).rows(2).Cells(2).Range.Start, _
           ActiveDocument.Tables(1).rows.Last.Cells(2).Range.End
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "ProposedMedTargets", Selection.Range
```

Comment: YES, Rich!!
That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

(Huh, I would have bet it wasn't possible to bookmark columns in Word - how about that...)

This can be done by selecting the cell in the second row, then extending the selection downwards by the count of the number of rows required. The sample code below sets the bookmark in the column where the selection is.

```
Sub SetBookmarkForColumn()
    Dim sel As Word.Selection
    Dim nrRows As Long

    Set sel = Selection
    If sel.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        nrRows = sel.Tables(1).Rows.Count
        sel.Columns(1).Cells(2).Select
        sel.MoveDown Count:=nrRows - 2, Extend:=True
        sel.Document.Bookmarks.Add "ProposedMedTargets", sel.Range
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Cindy, the only issue is I set the bookmarks programatically via other VBAs, so I won't be able to select the cells, the code needs to reference the range itself. My original macro is supposed to:
Create a table, bookmark the 6th column of that table (except headers)
Then a second VBA run at another time cuts the data from that bookmark and pastes it into another bookmarked column. This will be done over and over again throughout the document, so I can't get my users to manage it themselves.

Comment: @Sylvie this is just an example - you can certainly specify a specific the second cell in a specific column, then select that. But you do NEED to use Selection - you canNOT use a Range variable to designate a column or any part of a column. If you had provided code that works with a table I'd have used that as a basis - but you did not.

Comment: The code I provided does add a bookmark to the entire column though...There's a separate bookmark on the table, then on that selection the second Macro creates another column, then adds a bookmark to that column. No manual selecting is ever done.

Comment: @Sylvie Unless you're trying to insert a cross-reference somewhere to replicate that part of the column, I can't see the purpose of the bookmark; to replicate the cell contents in (or from) another table, for example, you'd still need to loop through the cells individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim r As Long, Rng As Range
Set Rng = Selection.Range
With ActiveDocument
  With .Tables(1)
    r = .Rows.Count - 2
    .Cell(2, 6).Range.Select
  End With
  Selection.MoveDown Count:=r, Extend:=True
  .Bookmarks.Add Name:="ProposedMedTargets", Range:=Selection
End With
Rng.Select
Set Rng = Nothing
```